# Why is RemoveRange not clearing DbSet?

Tags: c#, dbset

I have the following extension method for clearing `DbSet<T>`:

```
public static void Clear<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet)
{
    dbSet.RemoveRange(dbSet);
}
```

And the usage looks like this:

```
databaseContext.Users.Clear();
databaseContext.SaveChanges();
```

Now the question: why is the code not working, why is the table Users not empty?

### EDIT

The correct answer is that `SaveChanges` throws an exception because of mutual entity relations and so some entities are not removed. I failed to notice the exception because it ran as a cleanup of a [integration] MSTest suite with all tests passing. But still, my original implementation did contain another mistake so I'm marking one of the responses pointing it out as **the** response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution).
Try:

```
 dbSet.RemoveRange(dbSet.ToList());
```

Answer (score 2):

In the context you are executing RemoveRange, there is no any rows retrieved from database. By adding ToList() before RemoveRange `dbSet.RemoveRange(dbSet.ToList())`, result is better. Please remember, that RemoveRange does delete one-by-one..

..where we come to performance. If you want to clear big amounts of data with good performance:

- Truncate table with SqlCommand (whole table) or
- Use bulk operations from [external library](http://entityframework.net/batch-delete)

Comment: Looks there's something fishy - I'm running this as clean-up code for my MSTest class, I clear all the ```DbSet```s one by one and then ```SaveChanges```, but if I add one extra SaveChanges into this sequence, everything up to this first extra save command is cleared.